# Can't connect to MySQL Server on "mydomain.tld" (10060)

Tags: mysql, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I cannot seem to establish a MySQL Workbench connection to my Raspberry Pi 3 on a Raspbian based OS. I have a dynamic IP-Adress, that is why I am using a dynamic dns service by no-ip.com. My webserver and FTP server are working perfectly. The web server even successfully tried to reach out to the mysql server to find a user when using the login system. *The only problem I have is that I cannot connect to the database using MySQL Workbench on any user. Root and the newly created user cannot connect to it.*

I tried editing the `my.cnf` file in `/etc/mysql/` uncommenting the `bind-address` or even setting it to `0.0.0.0` and then reloading and restarting the MySQL service. But it does not seem to work.
[image]

The error message is *Cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:3306*

**Edit:** The Raspberry Pi 3 and I are both on the same network.

**Edit 2:** So I have installed PhpMyAdmin after 1 hour since I asked my question, and PhpMyAdmin is working perfectly. I don't know if this is MySQL Workbench fault or not, but I will leave the question open. I guess I will be using PhpMyAdmin instead..

Comment: Did you check your firewall rules for port 3306?

Comment: Not really. Can you please specify?

Comment: From the Pi, run ```sudo ufw allow 3306``` to allow incoming traffic to port 3306

Comment: Connected to my Raspberry via SSH and entered your command. Error message `Command not found`

Comment: What do you get when you run ```iptables -L```?  You could just allow all traffic with ```iptables --flush``` then ```iptables-save``` but that's not the best approach; something like ```sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT``` would be better.

Comment: [iptables -L](https://i.imgur.com/P4Lnnfc.png) This is what `iptables -L` looks like for me. After running `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` first, I get the same error message. Then tried `iptables --flush` + `iptables-save` and still get the error.. :/

Comment: Why aren't you just connecting to the Pi through its local IP address? You say you're on the same network, I'm not getting why you need to involve no-ip.com

Comment: I used the domain name as a connection for the IP Adress on MySQL Workbench because I do not want to change the IP Adress every time I want to connect to the database.. Even when entering my IP Adress I still get the same error.

Comment: By the looks of it, you seem to be trying to connect to the MySql database in your RPI from your computer, is that it?

Comment: It appears that you are running things on a single node (web, ftp, phpmyadmin) and they all work because they are all local.  The problem is your firewall and that's why external resources can't connect.  The first thing you need to figure out is what application is controlling your firewall, it is usually iptables but I am not super into debian or raspbian.  Once you know that, you can turn if off to verify it is in fact a firewall issue.  Then, reconfigure it to allow incoming 3306 traffic.

Comment: apparmour could also be your issue, but I still bet it is the firewall.  Research raspbian firewall and apparmour and turn them off.  If you can connect via MySQL Workbench, turn them back on and reconfig them.

Comment: By the image he show i think the problem is far more simpler. The image in the question from the workbench states that he tried to connect to the local IP (127.0.0.1) from his machine (I'm guessing that because he mentioned to be in the same network), so my bet is on a miss configuration on the workbench

Comment: And the popup error is clearly a windows message type

Comment: That's it.  I missed that.  You need to change Workbench to point to your Pi, not localhost.  Also, I booted my retropie which is raspbian based and iptables is the default firewall and flushing and saving works just fine.

Comment: "To point" to my Pi? Also @JorgeCampos, you are right. The image shows a windows type error. This is because I use MySQL Workbench on Windows 7.

Comment: Reconfigure your connection setting so that instead of localhost or 127.0.0.1 as the hostname, use the IP (or in your case, hostname you provided your dynamic dns provider).

Comment: You mean my domain? Ive been using my domain I got from no-ip.com for the connection adress the whole time.

Comment: I don't think they gave you localhost as your DNS name for the Pi.  What DNS name did they give you?  Obfuscate it a bit so it's not publicly known.

Comment: Also, if you are using that for your whole network (i.e. your public IP), you will need to configure your router to route incoming traffic to your Pi.

Comment: I never said that I was using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as the hostname for the connection. I think you guys got that mixed up because I provided that image, which I did not make. My DNS name I got is something like `appname.ddns.net`. I also have port forwarding set on my router, that is how my connections to the Pi are set up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144754/discussion-between-spechal-and-dean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ultimately ended up being that MySQL was not seeing the hostname properly and was rejecting connections based on this.  It was verified to work by allowing connections from any host.  Advised to lock it back down to the connecting host.